# Зачем подписывать APK файл?

Tags: android, apk

Я так понял, что apk файл нужно подписывать просто, чтоб отметить свой бренд? Но по сути этот файл никто не видит толком...

Клиент когда скачивает приложение на телефон, он ведь не смотрит как подписан файл?

И второе, а если прописывать имя файла не через билд, а просто после создания файла его переименовать?

Comment: Телефон ещё как смотрит на подпись (если только спецгалочку не поставить). 

А переименовать можно, насколько я знаю, имя не входит в подпись.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

По умолчанию `apk` файл подписывается `debug` ключом. Он отличается от `release` ключа по сути только сроком действия. `release` ключ должен быть действителен 10 тыс. дней. `debug` ключ генерируется автоматически со сроком действия только 365 дней.

Выложить в маркет `apk` файл не подписанный `release` ключом нельзя. Также нельзя обновить приложение в маркете если ключ утерян.

По умолчанию на телефон можно установить приложения только из маркета, из-за стандартной настройки безопасности девайса.

Если включить опцию "Разрешить установку из непроверенных источников", можно устанавливать приложения, подписанные любым ключем. Но обязательно подписанные, без подписи приложения не устанавливаются системой вообще.

Так же подпись подтверждает что автор данного приложения именно вы и её тяжело подделать, если кто-то добавит в ваше приложение (например с помощью `apktool`) вредноносную часть (локер, троян, рекламу или иное) вы можете проверив подпись доказать что это не вы, а пользователь может проверив подпись не устанавливать приложение.

Comment: я хотел бы добавить, что подпись защищает вас от ситуации, когда кто-то взял приложение, добавил всякой гадости (троян, локер etc) и выложил от вашего имени.

Comment: @pavel, не буду возражать, если вы это в ответ через правку добавите)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, при всем уважении :), в первых двух абзацах ответа неточности. "Стандартные настройки безопасности" различают только источники, откуда ставится приложение, сертификат подписи абсолютно не важен. А то что это стандартно только маркет, а в маркете все подписано релизным ключем, это уже следствие третьего абзаца. Но никак не причина.

Comment: @Eugene Krivenja, не буду возражать против правок ответа)